# strange character in oracle table (preventing conversion to XML)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a string in a table with something odd in it. When I Open it in toad, you see a gray mark at the end of it:

[image]

When I try to convert it into XML like this, a error is triggered:

```
select xmlelement ("x",value)
from bad_strings;

ORA-31061: XDB-fout: special char to escaped char conversion failed.
```

If I export it to a text file (using utl_file), the strange character is removed. If I open it in sqldevelopet, it's not visible either.

Now I am curious what it is (and how it got there, but that's another story). I though I could just use ascii() to see what it's ascii value is, but that doesn't seem to work.

If I ask for the length of the string, I get 48, wich is the length of the visible characters.
Looking at the ascii code with a script like this doesn't reveil anything out of the ordinary:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
   l_string   VARCHAR2 (600);
   l_stringlen number;
BEGIN
   SELECT   VALUE
     INTO   l_string
     FROM   bad_strings
    WHERE   pk = 195789220;

    l_stringlen := length(l_string);

    for x in 1..l_stringlen
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(x || ':    ' || substr(l_string,x,1) || ' --> ' || ascii(substr(l_string,x,1))) ;
    end loop;
 END;



1:    v --> 118
2:    e --> 101
3:    r --> 114
4:    h --> 104
5:    u --> 117
6:    i --> 105
7:    s --> 115
8:    t --> 116
9:      --> 32
10:    b --> 98
11:    i --> 105
12:    n --> 110
13:    n --> 110
14:    e --> 101
15:    n --> 110
16:    k --> 107
17:    o --> 111
18:    r --> 114
19:    t --> 116
20:      --> 32
21:    n --> 110
22:    a --> 97
23:    a --> 97
24:    r --> 114
25:      --> 32
26:    b --> 98
27:    u --> 117
28:    i --> 105
29:    t --> 116
30:    e --> 101
31:    n --> 110
32:    l --> 108
33:    a --> 97
34:    n --> 110
35:    d --> 100
36:      --> 32
37:     --> 29
38:    2 --> 50
39:    1 --> 49
40:    - --> 45
41:    1 --> 49
42:    0 --> 48
43:    - --> 45
44:    2 --> 50
45:    0 --> 48
46:    1 --> 49
47:    3 --> 51
48:    ) --> 41
```

Neither does dumping it:

```
select value, dump(value,1017) from bad_strings
where pk = 195789220;

Typ=1 Len=48 CharacterSet=WE8MSWIN1252: v,e,r,h,u,i,s,t, ,b,i,n,n,e,n,k,o,r,t, ,n,a,a,r, ,b,u,i,t,e,n,l,a,n,d, ,^],2,1,-,1,0,-,2,0,1,3,)
```

So I'm a bit puzzled. What is this weird character that is preventing me from converting it into XML? 
any ideas?

I'm using Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit

Comment: `37:     --> 29` wich is `^]` is your problem character

Comment: Thanks, you're right, see my comment on user3465652's post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about copying the text and pasting it into Notepad++? You can set it to 'Show All Characters' so you can see everything. I had a similar issue with one value, it was some HTML character. I don't really remember which one.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually a very good suggestion. I already did the same in textpad, so though pasting it in notepad++ wouldn't help me, but tried it any way. Turns out there's a "Group separator" in the middle of the sentence, which is ascii code 29 that already was showing up in my list of ascii codes.  I was so much focusing on high ascii codes and on the end of the string that I didn't notice it.